# Failure to Install Pystan in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, pystan

I have the following line in jupyter notebook:

```
 !pip install pystan
```

However, I am getting the following error followed by a whole large block of code:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

With the following block of output at the end:

```
 IOPub data rate exceeded.
 The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
 to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
 To change this limit, set the config variable
 `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

 Current values:
 NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
 NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I went through a lot of solutions to a dead end. I can't install pystan because it requires installing httpstan, which is exclusive to Mac and linux. I am on a PC.